# MATLAB: Replace column in cell array with NaN

Tags: matlab, cell-array

I have a 3x2 cell array `data` where each cell contains a double matrix. It looks something like this:

```
{600x4 double} {600x4x3 double}
{600x4 double} {600x4x3 double}
{600x4 double} {600x4x3 double}
```

Now, I would like to replace the second column of the cell array with NaNs. The result should therefore look like this:

```
{600x4 double} {[NaN]}
{600x4 double} {[NaN]}
{600x4 double} {[NaN]}
```

Using curly braces is leading nowhere.

```
data{:,2} = nan
Expected one output from a curly brace or dot indexing expression, but there were 3 results.
```

I think I could use `cellfun` or a simple for-loop to change the values to `NaN`. However, I would like to know if there's a more simple solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this

```
data(:,2) = {NaN};
```

Logic:

```
% Assign all values in the 2nd column of the cell ...
% All elements should be the single cell {NaN};
```

---

You can alternatively do this (slightly clearer logic)

```
data(:,2) = repmat( {NaN}, size(data,1), 1 ); % Right hand side is same height as data
```

---

Or even this!

```
data(:,2) = num2cell( NaN(size(data,1), 1 ) );
```

Comment: Also `[data{:,2}] = deal(NaN)`

Comment: @Wolfie Your first suggestion is straight forward. Actually very easy ;-) Thanks.

Comment: @Luis damn I couldn't get that one to click, I was missing the `deal`!